# [SQLServer JDBC Driver]Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis

I am getting the following error. Let me know the possible reason to get this error. I don't have Apps code. whenever we get this error. we restart the Application. not Db server. it get resolved. Let me know what makes this error to occur?

```
(:initial ( (:initial java.sql.SQLException: [Vignette Corp.][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Connection reset by peer: socket write error)(:msg [Vignette Corp.][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Connection reset by peer: socket write error[1.65.143884]) ))(:msg remote queue failure) )
    at com.intraspect.objrel.collect.RemoteQueue.size(RemoteQueue.java:237)
    at com.intraspect.objrel.collect.LocalSharedQueue.size(LocalSharedQueue.java:98)
    at com.intraspect.scapi.datamodel.PersistentSharedQueue.size(PersistentSharedQueue.java:166)
    at com.intraspect.scapi.datamodel.Notification.processNotifications(Notification.java:287)
    at com.intraspect.scapi.datamodel.Notification.dailyProcessNotifications(Notification.java:263)
    at com.intraspect.background.NotificationHandler$1.doit(NotificationHandler.java:32)
    at com.intraspect.database.WrapTransaction.withCommandStateNew(WrapTransaction.java:251)
    at com.intraspect.database.WrapTransaction.withCommandState(WrapTransaction.java:212)
    at com.intraspect.database.WrapTransaction.withCommandState(WrapTransaction.java:107)
    at com.intraspect.database.WrapTransaction.withCommandState(WrapTransaction.java:92)
    at com.intraspect.database.WrapTransaction.withCommandState(WrapTransaction.java:83)
    at com.intraspect.database.WrapTransaction.withCommandState(WrapTransaction.java:76)
    at com.intraspect.background.NotificationHandler.dailyNotificationReporting(NotificationHandler.java:39)
    at com.intraspect.background.NotificationHandler.doIt(NotificationHandler.java:14)
    at com.intraspect.background.BackgroundJobHandler.run(BackgroundJobHandler.java:92)
Caused by: ( (:initial java.sql.SQLException: [Vignette Corp.][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Connection reset by peer: socket write error)(:msg [Vignette Corp.][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Connection reset by peer: socket write error[1.65.143884]) )
    at com.intraspect.objrel.db.jdbc.JDBCUtil.wrapException(JDBCUtil.java:68)
    at com.intraspect.objrel.db.jdbc.JDBCUtil.wrapException(JDBCUtil.java:27)
    at com.intraspect.objrel.db.jdbc.JDBCAttribute.fetchCollectionElements(JDBCAttribute.java:658)
    at com.intraspect.objrel.db.relational.RAttribute.fetchCollectionElements(RAttribute.java:111)
    at com.intraspect.objrel.db.jdbc.JDBCDatabase.loadQueue(JDBCDatabase.java:856)
    at com.intraspect.objrel.remote.collect.RRemoteQueue.<init>(RRemoteQueue.java:48)
    at com.intraspect.objrel.remote.collect.RQueueMgr.getQueue(RQueueMgr.java:250)
    at com.intraspect.objrel.remote.collect.RQueueMgr.size(RQueueMgr.java:318)
    at com.intraspect.objrel.collect.RemoteQueue.size(RemoteQueue.java:234)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Vignette Corp.][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at com.vignette.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.createException(Unknown Source)
    at com.vignette.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.getException(Unknown Source)
    at com.vignette.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.getException(Unknown Source)
    at com.vignette.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRPCRequest.submitRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.vignette.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRPCNonCursorExecuteRequest.submitPrepExec(Unknown Source)
    at com.vignette.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRPCExecuteRequest.doPrepExec(Unknown Source)
    at com.vignette.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRPCExecuteRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.vignette.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerImplStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.vignette.jdbc.base.BaseStatement.commonExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.vignette.jdbc.base.BaseStatement.executeQueryInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.vignette.jdbc.base.BasePreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.intraspect.objrel.db.jdbc.JDBCAttribute.fetchCollectionElements(JDBCAttribute.java:642)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: It is not TDS server. It is SQLserver 2005 server.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this to happen on a TDS server (i.e. Microsoft or Sybase) is that the application attempted to send a new query before it finished processing the results from the previous one.  If your application is portable across DBMS products, it may well be that it behaves in that way, because other DBMS products don't have that restriction.

You may also find this [FreeTDS FAQ](http://www.freetds.org/faq.html#pending) entry interesting.